# Create Anonymous Method that returns a value to a variable

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function

I'm working on a C# project, I want to use an anonymous Method Or Function that returns a value to a variable.

I tried this :

```
    byte[] V;
    V= new byte[]()
    {
        //Some code here
        return new byte[]{0,1,2,3};
        
    }
```

But I got errors

How can I use anonymous Method Or Function to returns a value to V variable ?

I want just to knw how can I use anonymous method tat returns a value to a variable.

Comment: why do you want an anonymous method that you execite immediately? Why even **anonymous**? Even there´s some logic that can be extracted to a method that has a name describing what it´s supposed to do, or there´s nothing to be extracted at all. There are local functions, however

Comment: Please explain the rationale behind wanting to use a function for this, in place of just having the code directly placed in your main code path. In the code in your question there is absolutely no need for a function at all, and knowing why you want to do this might indicate better approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of opportunities, all having their own advantages and disadvantages.

1. a delegate

   ```
   byte[] V;
   V= new Func<byte[]>(() => ()
   {
       //Some code here
       return new byte[]{0,1,2,3};    
   }();
   ```
2. a local function

   ```
   void DoSomething()
   {
       byte[] V;

       byte[]MyLocalFunction()
       {
           //Some code here
           return new byte[]{0,1,2,3};
       }
       V = MyLocalFunction();
   }
   ```
3. a normal private method with a name

Personally I prefer 3 the most, as you have a name that clearly describes what the method should do. 2 also has a name and in fact compiles to a private static method within your class, so it may seem appropriate as well. 1 just makes your code har to understand and read. There are use-caes for that, but in most cases I won´t suggest to use it.

So if you think there is some logic within a member that should be extracted in some way, you give it a name. This way you can easily extract that to another class later on, if you need to.

Comment: If you are on .net core and the data is supposed to be readonly, a ReadOnlySpan<Byte> is far better in terms of performance since that will end up being written to static data section of the binary.

Comment: Massive thanks #HimBromBeere, this is a very beneficial answer, I really appreciate this for you, again let me say massive thanks sir and please accept all my respect.